# Word/phrase for nationally owned company

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word/phrase for a company whose owners are all from the U.S.?

When I search for "nationally owned company", Google returns "Government-owned corporation", which is not what I am after.

Would it be "fully U.S.-owned"? ("Fully" for emphasis.)

Comment: Can you give an example? Some "private companies" in the UK are (or were) constrained by (government-instigated) rules preventing non-Brits from owning a controlling interest (i.e. - more than 50% of the voting shares). But I don't see why a company would have a rule preventing "foreigners" from buying their shares at all (or indeed, how they could reliably *enforce* such a rule).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not involved in the regulations/politics of this matter.  It is written as such in the text I am translating.  The company in question is a defense firm.

Comment: "Nationally Owned" means OWNED BY THE GOVERNMENT.

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes I know, from Google results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Wholly owned" US corporation would probably be closest for general use. Phrases like "wholly owned subsidiary" are commonly understood.

There might be specific legal terms like "Canadian Controlled Private Corporation" if you are writing about some complex tax or legal treatment.